# How is primitive type int actually converted to a String?

Tags: java, string, int, tostring

Firstly, my question is about how the primitive type `int` is able to be converted into a `String` without being an Object, so not having a `toString()` method to get the `String` value.
I'm well aware of how you're able to seemingly 'convert' a variable of the primitive type `int` to a `String` in Java. The most simple way I use is:

```
int x = 5;
String y = "" + x;
```

This works very well, however my question is the following:
Due to the primitive type `int` not being an Object, therefore not having any methods such as the `toString()` method which to my knowledge is required in order to get a `String` value of a variable... How is the value of the variable recognised without this fundamental method?

Comment: This was already possible before auto-boxing existed. It is just built into the language I would say.

Comment: So is an int converted into an Integer object which has the toString() method enabling it to be recognised as a String via auto-boxing?

Comment: See rgettman's answer. It is converted but it is not strictly speaking autoboxing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, an `int` value is converted to `String` by calling one of these two methods:

- [`StringBuilder.append(int i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append-int-)
- [`String.valueOf(int i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-int-)

For other primitive values, the corresponding overload of either of these methods are used.

**StringBuilder.append()**

The expression `"" + x` is implemented by the compiler as:

```
new StringBuilder().append("").append(x).toString()
```

With `x` being declared as `int`, that means that the overload of `append()` that takes an `int` parameter will be called.

The source (Java 1.8.0_65) for [`append(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append-int-) is:

```
@Override
public StringBuilder append(int i) {
    super.append(i);
    return this;
}
```

The `super` call leads to:

```
public AbstractStringBuilder append(int i) {
    if (i == Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
        append("-2147483648");
        return this;
    }
    int appendedLength = (i < 0) ? Integer.stringSize(-i) + 1
                                 : Integer.stringSize(i);
    int spaceNeeded = count + appendedLength;
    ensureCapacityInternal(spaceNeeded);
    Integer.getChars(i, spaceNeeded, value);
    count = spaceNeeded;
    return this;
}
```

**String.valueOf()**

When converting a value to a String without using string concatenation, it is generally done by calling `String.valueOf()`. For an `int` value that means [`valueOf(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-int-):

```
public static String valueOf(int i) {
    return Integer.toString(i);
}
```

The `Integer.toString()` call is:

```
public static String toString(int i) {
    if (i == Integer.MIN_VALUE)
        return "-2147483648";
    int size = (i < 0) ? stringSize(-i) + 1 : stringSize(i);
    char[] buf = new char[size];
    getChars(i, size, buf);
    return new String(buf, true);
}
```

**Integer.getChars()**

As you can see, both do it by actually calling the package-private method `Integer.getChars(int i, int index, char[] buf)`.

Neither of them actually creates an instance of `Integer`, even though the JLS implies it would.

Answer (score 11):

This is called *string conversion*.  The [JLS, Section 5.1.11](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11), states:

> Any type may be converted to type `String` by *string conversion*.
>
> A value x of primitive type T is first converted to a reference value as if by giving it as an argument to an appropriate class instance creation expression (§15.9):

(other types)

> - If T is `byte`, `short`, or `int`, then use `new Integer(x)`.

This reference value is then converted to type String by string conversion.

Now only reference values need to be considered:

> - If the reference is `null`, it is converted to the string `"null"` (four ASCII characters `n`, `u`, `l`, `l`).
> - Otherwise, the conversion is performed as if by an invocation of the `toString` method of the referenced object with no arguments; but if the result of invoking the `toString` method is `null`, then the string `"null"` is used instead.

So, the `int` is converted to an `Integer`, not by boxing conversion, but by `new Integer(x)`, then `toString()` is called on it.

It's technically not a boxing conversion; string conversion has been in the language since the beginning of Java, where boxing conversions were added in Java 1.5.

Comment: In reality, the exact logic described by the JLS is not applied. Instead, *string conversion* is implemented by calling `String.valueOf()`, which has overloads to take care of the primitive values. The implementation doesn't actually create an instance of `Integer`, which is ok, because the *result* is the same as if it had.

Comment: @Andreas the JLS does state "as if", so technically it's not required to create a new `Integer`, but what proves that it's generating the calls you state in your answer?

Comment: Hmmm, yeah, I can't seem to find any examples for `String.valueOf()` being used for *string conversion*, although the methods are implementing string conversion to the specification. All the examples in the JLS are for string concatenation. As for that, disassembling the bytecode is proof that `StringBuilder.append()` is used.

Comment: Checking the callers of `valueOf(int)` shows that they are used by the `print(int)` methods of `PrintStream` and `PrintWriter`, which makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**valueOf**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_valueof.htm) method for *static String* for primitive types, such as int, double, float. Some code:

```
int intValue  = 25;
String s = String.valueOf(intValue);
```

Comment: I'm aware of the valueOf() method for String objects. My question was how is the value of the primitive type int recognised due to the lack of a toString() method. But thank you for your response.

Comment: @Nathangrad It is recognized by the overloads of `String.valueOf()`, which means [`valueOf(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28int%29) when the value is an `int`. In your listed case (`"" + x`), it is however recognized by the overloads of `StringBuilder.append()`, meaning [`append(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append%28int%29).

Comment: @Andreas Are you suggesting that the StringBuilder.append() method is implied when I use a primitive type such as int alongside a String in order to get it's String value?

Comment: @Nathangrad I am saying that `"" + x` is converted to `new StringBuilder().append("").append(x).toString()` by the compiler. If you disassemble the bytecode using `javap -c Xxx.class`, you'll see that. It is how the Java compiler implements string concatenation.

Comment: @Andreas Regardless of what the compiler converts it to, the value of x still needs to be obtained by the StringBuilder.append() method. I was trying to understand how the value of x is retrieved from methods without having a toString() method invoked on it due to it not being an object.

Comment: @Nathangrad A `toString()` method or other similar code *is* being called. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35633492/5221149) for more detail.